# What is the ugriz magnitude system?

Tags: galaxy, photometry, magnitude

While studying photometric redshifts, I came across the ugriz (or u'g'r'i'z) system for classifying magnitudes of galaxies, but I didn't find much information on the internet about how it works.

Can somebody explain that? Do the letters "ugriz" have any special meaning, or is its just a nomenclature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"ugriz" is short for U-band, G-band, R-band, I-band, and Z-band, detailed on [the Wikipedia article on photometric systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_system):
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline \text{Band}&\text{Effective Wavelength Midpoint }(\lambda_{\text{eff}})\\
\hline \text{U} & \text{365 nm}\\
\hline \text{G} & \sim\text{475 nm}\\
\hline \text{R} & \text{658 nm}\\
\hline \text{I} & \text{806 nm}\\
\hline \text{Z} & \text{900 nm}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
This $ugriz$ system is slightly different from the $u'g'r'i'z'$ system; conversions can be found [here](http://classic.sdss.org/dr4/algorithms/jeg_photometric_eq_dr1.html#usno2SDSS). The starting point is the same (note that $u(\text{2.5m})=u'$), but there are slight vertical and horizontal shifts.

The differences between $ugriz$ and $u'g'r'i'z'$ are much smaller than the differences between $u'g'r'i'z'$ and the $UBV(RI)_C$ system, which was replaced by them both. This older system of filters had large overlaps and did not cover as broad a range. See Fig. 1 from [this thesis](http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~jclem/publications/phd.pdf) for a comparison:

[image]

Comment: I think its worth pointing out that ugriz and u'g'r'i'z' are two different, but similar systems.

Comment: @zephyr Very good point. Done.